# Continuous Service

Tags: android

I am trying to run the service continously in background but it was closed when the service runs more than 2 hrs. I tried to put android:enabled="true" in manifest and placed START_NOT_STICKY in onStartCommand

Comment: Make it `START_STICKY`. It will be restarted when it is killed.

Comment: `START_STICKY` means it will be restarted _if_ the OS feels like it. Try making it a foreground service.

Comment: How to run the service continously in background. My service getting stopped even I replaced as START_STICKY